# Bold text in footer, cannot figure out why it is styled bold...stumped

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Cannot figure out why the copyright section is bold on this single webpage of a WordPress website: https://podcastmillions.com/testimonials all other pages the copyright is not bold.

I've searched through the code looking for an unclosed `</strong>` tag, I've tried adding font-weight: normal !important; but nothing seem to make a difference.

I'm stumped. Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Small tip, not really relevant to your question but here it goes anyway: You are trying to hide your terms and conditions link? It's allmost unvisible and the image is partially in front of it. Master Google will not like that.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: TVBZ, appreciate the input. The clients want's it this way.

Answer (score 0):

This is because on this page you are loading Open Sans with single font-weight unlike other pages.
Look at this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" id="fl-builder-google-fonts-13b1030219735b0dde02670632688827-css" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans%3A800&amp;ver=5.1.1" type="text/css" media="all">
```

Only 800-weight is loaded. Check fl-builder settings on that page I guess

Answer (score 0):

You are loading different font-family sets on compared to other pages. This particular page loads this font:

```
https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans%3A800&ver=5.1.1
```

While other pages load this version:

```
https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans%3A800%2C700%2C600%2C400&ver=5.1.1
```

Notice the different numbers? Those are the `font-weight` numbers. Modify your imported fonts to fixed it.